# Java printf functionality for collections or arrays

Tags: java, collections, printf

In python you can use a tuple in a formatted print statement and the tuple values are used at the indicated positions in the formatted string.  For example:

```
>>> a = (1,"Hello",7.2)
>>> print "these are the values %d, %s, %f" % a
these are the values 1, Hello, 7.200000
```

Is there some way to use any array or collection in a java printf statement in a similar way?

I've looked at the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and it appears to have built in support for some types like Calendar, but I don't see anything for collections.

If this isn't provided in java, is there any java idiom that would be used in a case like this where you are populating collections and then printing the values from many collections using one format string (other than just nested looping)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

printf will have a declaration along the lines of:

```
public PrintString printf(String format, Object... args);
```

... means much the same as `[]`. The difference is `...` allows the caller to omit explicitly creating an array. So consider:

```
    out.printf("%s:%s", a, b);
```

That is the equivalent of:

```
    out.printf("%s:%s", new Object[] { a, b });
```

So, getting back to your question, for an array, you can just write:

```
    out.printf("%s:%s", things);
```

For a collection:

```
    out.printf("%s:%s", things.toArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested by the [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class too.